# how can i fix TypeError: stagedAutoprefixer is not a function?

Tags: html, reactjs

currently getting : TypeError: stagedAutoprefixer is not a function.

Currently using https://startbootstrap.com/template/sb-admin for project and this is my error:

```
./src/assets/admin/css/styles.css (./node_modules/css-loader??ref--6-oneOf-3-1!./node_modules/postcss-loader/src??postcss!./src/assets/admin/css/styles.css)
TypeError: stagedAutoprefixer is not a function
```

how can i fix it?